# Getting the accurate character from keys pressed

Tags: c#, opentk

I'm working with an OpenTK window and I am trying to create a hand-made text-box for a GUI.

The issue I'm running into here is getting proper keyboard input.

For example, when the user types <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>, the character that appears in the text-field is an exclamation mark.

The issue is, using input libraries just give me raw key presses. ie, pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> gives you an event where shift is being pressed, and an event where 1 is being pressed.

I'm looking to know if there is a way to convert these presses into the appropriate character, so that they can use whatever special characters they have available on their keyboard.

If this feature is not available - would the best approach be to hard-code the appropriate keys when modifiers are used with them?

---

**EDIT:** I changed the event I was using from KeyDown to KeyPress - it gives a different event which handles the modifiers correctly. Thank you for all the help!

Comment: `Do not Hard Code`[Get keys that are pressed](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=c%23%20stackoverflow%20getting%20keys%20that%20were%20pressed) do a google search if the link provided does not serve your purpose

Comment: How would I go about doing this then?

Comment: In which event are you capturing the input?  Perhaps you need to catch it in an event down the pipe a ways, so you wouldn't see the `shift` event, but once the `1` was pressed, you would get a `!` result.

Comment: you go about it by deciding which `Event` you need to wire-up depending on your use case.. which also you would go about it by starting to write some code...

Comment: As I said - you could hard-code it so that when you press both buttons that an '!' appears - but not all keyboards have it labelled that shift+1 = '!'; that's the issue with hard-coding

Comment: Nobody said anything about hard coding.  I am suggesting using the `KeyDown` event instead of `KeyPress` (I think those are the ones I am thinking of).. if you use the right `Event`, as @MethodMan said, you won't have to handle the `shift` key separately.

Comment: This actually fixed my problem - but it was the other way around. Regardless, cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use ***keypress EventHandler*** of Your control
then

```
if(e.keychar==(char)keys.[specified key])do some work
```

***e*** is Argument of keypress eventhandler function

Comment: you mean for example (shift+f) together?